# фильтрация массива другим массивом

Tags: javascript

Есть два массива. В одном массиве содержатся выбранные пользователем теги (жанры кино), а во втором массиве находятся сами фильмы .

Примерная структура массивов :

```js
//массив с фильмами
data = [
{"title" : "фильм1", "tags" : ["драма", "мистика"]},
{"title" : "фильм2", "tags" : ["драма", "боевик"]},
{"title" : "фильм3", "tags" : ["ужасы", "боевик"]}
]
//массив с искомыми жанрами
selectedTags = ["драма"]

//result возвращает пустой массив, а ожидалось что будет с фильм1 и фильм2
let result = data.filter( e => selectedTags.includes(e.tags) );

//result возвращает false
let result = data.some( e => selectedTags.indexOf(e.tags) >= 0);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let data = [
  {"title" : "фильм1", "tags" : ["драма", "мистика"]},
  {"title" : "фильм2", "tags" : ["драма", "боевик", "бубу"]},
  {"title" : "фильм3", "tags" : ["ужасы", "боевик"]}
];

let selectedTags = ["ужасы", "бубу"];

let result = data.filter( ({tags: arr}) => arr.some( tag => selectedTags.includes(tag) ) );

console.log( result );
```

А для строгой фильтрации:

```js
let data = [
  {"title" : "фильм1", "tags" : ["драма", "мистика"]},
  {"title" : "фильм2", "tags" : ["драма", "боевик", "бубу"]},
  {"title" : "фильм3", "tags" : ["ужасы", "боевик"]}
];

let selectedTags = ["боевик", "бубу"];

let result = data.filter( movie => selectedTags.every( tag => movie.tags.includes(tag) ) );

console.log( result );
```

Хотя на самом деле я бы предпочел чуть длинный классический цикл, чем вникать в эльфийский код)

Comment: и почему я не удивлен что первый ответ от Вас ?

Comment: Спасибо! А что если хочется сортировать объекты более строго ? Ну в плане, что идёт фильтрация по всем тэгам внутри selectedTags, а не исключительно по их , так сказать, совокупности. Если я выберу 'ужасы' и 'боевик' то должно вывести фильм3, а не все фильмы где есть и ужасы и боевик отдельно